# Why can't I access the array item without using an "if" function

Tags: javascript, date

I keep getting the error

```
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2') at script.js:18:47"
```

unless I put it in an if function.

Here's the array

```
['title','title',new Date("2022-03-26T10:00:00-06:00"),new Date("2022-04-02T10:00:00-06:00")],
['title','title',new Date("2022-04-02T10:00:00-06:00"),new Date("2022-04-09T10:00:00-06:00")],
['title', 'title', new Date("2022-04-09T10:00:00-06:00"), new Date("2022-04-16T10:00:00-06:00")],
['title', 'title', new Date("2022-04-16T10:00:00-06:00"), new Date("2022-04-23T10:00:00-06:00")],
['title', 'title', new Date("2022-04-23T10:00:00-06:00"), new Date("2022-04-30T10:00:00-06:00")],
['title', 'title', new Date("2022-04-30T10:00:00-06:00"), new Date("2022-05-07T10:00:00-06:00")],
['title', 'title', new Date("2022-05-07T10:00:00-06:00"), new Date("2022-05-14T10:00:00-06:00")],
['title', 'title', new Date("2022-05-14T10:00:00-06:00"), new Date("2022-05-21T10:00:00-06:00")],
['title', 'title', new Date("2022-05-21T10:00:00-06:00"), new Date("2022-05-28T10:00:00-06:00")]
];
```

Doesn't Work:

```
var today = Date.now();
var weeksPassed = Math.floor((today - Date.parse(nextRelease))/(24*3600*1000*7));
var latestRelease = episodeList[weeksPassed][2];
var nextRelease = episodeList[weeksPassed][3];
document.getElementById("previousEpisode").innerHTML = episodeList[weeksPassed][0];
document.getElementById("nextEpisode").innerHTML = episodeList[weeksPassed][1]
```

Works:

```
var nextRelease = new Date("2022-03-26T10:00:00-06:00");
var today = Date.now();
if (today > nextRelease) {
  var weeksPassed = Math.floor((today - Date.parse(nextRelease))/(24*3600*1000*7));
  latestRelease = episodeList[weeksPassed][2];
  nextRelease = episodeList[weeksPassed][3];
  document.getElementById("previousEpisode").innerHTML = episodeList[weeksPassed][0];
  document.getElementById("nextEpisode").innerHTML = episodeList[weeksPassed][1]
};
```

Comment: Because `weeksPassed` isn't a valid index in the array.

Comment: BTW, `if` isn't a loop. A loop is something that repeats, like `for` and `while`.

Comment: @Barmar It's been reading it as a variable. Right now weeksPassed = 0.

Comment: maybe first use `console.log()` to see what you have in variables.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with `var nextRelease = new Date("2022-03-26T10:00:00-06:00");`. That's missing from your first code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not very good at JavaScript, but i think youre using next release without initializing it properly so an exception is thrown down the line that cascades from that

Comment: Yes you're correct. It was a dumb mistake on my part.